# Is there a way to fix audio A from playing after audio B has also started playing?

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avplayer, avaudiosession

I'm building an app where users can select an audio file to be played. That normally works and it plays it even when screen is locked. The problem is that after the audio file has been changed by the user the first audio file still plays in the background and overlaps with the file the user wants to listen to.

```swift
let player: AVPlayer = {
        let avPlay = AVPlayer()
        avPlay.allowsExternalPlayback = false
        avPlay.automaticallyWaitsToMinimizeStalling = false
        return avPlay
    }()

fileprivate func setupLockScreenCurrentTime(){
        var nowPlayingInfo = MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().nowPlayingInfo
//      nowPlayingInfo = nil

        guard let currentItem = player.currentItem else{return}
        let durationInSecs = CMTimeGetSeconds(currentItem.duration)
//      let elapsed = CMTimeGetSeconds(player.currentTime())
        nowPlayingInfo?[MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration] = durationInSecs

        MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().nowPlayingInfo = nowPlayingInfo
    }
fileprivate func playSermon(){
        let credential = URLCredential(user: "1234user" , password: "password", persistence: .forSession)
        let protectionSpace = URLProtectionSpace(host: "example.com", port: 443, protocol: "https", realm: "Restricted", authenticationMethod: NSURLAuthenticationMethodHTTPBasic)
        URLCredentialStorage.shared.setDefaultCredential(credential, for: protectionSpace)
        let ssurl = SermonHelper.sharedInstance.url
        let urlNew:String = ssurl.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "%20")
        guard let url = URL(string: urlNew) else {return}
        let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url)
        player.replaceCurrentItem(with: playerItem)
        player.isMuted = false
        player.play()
        observePlayerCurrentTime()

    }

fileprivate func setupRemoteControl(){
        UIApplication.shared.beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()

        let commandCenter = MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared()
        commandCenter.playCommand.isEnabled = true
        commandCenter.playCommand.addTarget { (_) -> MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus in
            self.player.play()
            self.enlargeEpisodeImageView()
            self.playPauseButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "my_pause2"), for: .normal)
            self.setupElapsedTime(rate: 1)
            return .success
        }

        commandCenter.pauseCommand.isEnabled = true
        commandCenter.pauseCommand.addTarget { (_) -> MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus in
            self.player.pause()
            self.shrinkEpisodeImageView()
            self.playPauseButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "my_play2"), for: .normal)
            self.setupElapsedTime(rate: 0)
            return .success
        }

        commandCenter.togglePlayPauseCommand.isEnabled = true
        commandCenter.togglePlayPauseCommand.addTarget { (_) -> MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus in
            if self.player.timeControlStatus == .playing {
                self.player.pause()
                self.shrinkEpisodeImageView()
                self.playPauseButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "my_play2"), for: .normal)
            }
            else {
                self.player.play()
                self.enlargeEpisodeImageView()
                self.playPauseButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "my_pause2"), for: .normal)
            }
            return .success
        }
        commandCenter.skipForwardCommand.isEnabled = true
        commandCenter.skipForwardCommand.addTarget { (_) -> MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus in
            self.seekToCurrentTime(delta: 15)
            let t = CMTimeAdd(self.player.currentTime(), CMTimeMake(15, 1))
            MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().nowPlayingInfo?[MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyElapsedPlaybackTime] = CMTimeGetSeconds(t)
            return .success
        }

        commandCenter.skipBackwardCommand.isEnabled = true
        commandCenter.skipBackwardCommand.addTarget { (_) -> MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus in
            self.seekToCurrentTime(delta: -15)
            let n = CMTimeAdd(self.player.currentTime(), CMTimeMake(-15, 1))
            MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().nowPlayingInfo?[MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyElapsedPlaybackTime] = CMTimeGetSeconds(n)
            return .success
        }
    }
```

I expect the audio being played to be replaced by the new audio file selected by the user, but I get the audio from two files being played simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

Nowhere in your code is indicated when you stop playing the current sound before replacing it with the new sound in `playSermon()`. Try to do that. Most probably that will solve your problem.

Comment: I assumed using  `player.replaceCurrentItem(with: playerItem)` in `playSermon()` would achieve that. If not what would be your suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: Pause the player just before you replace the item in playSermon().

Comment: Do you mean the sound keeps playing even after you pause the player? What happens if you do omit the replacement code?

Comment: I think the issue is that anytime the view controller is initialised a new instance of `AVPlayer` is created. Is there a safe way to stop this from happening.

Comment: Then you should not instantiate the AVPlayer in your view controller. What I normally do is I create a class handling the creation and the destruction of AVPlayer's containing an array that points to all AVPlayer's I want to control.

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what I need. Could you provide me with an example. Thanks.